# How to fill the background-color only for padding for Bootstrap's container-fluid?

Tags: html, css

I try to fill only the padding of container-fluid with a background-color. 
My container-fluid has a padding of `0 120px`

I found out that it should work like that

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 120px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background: grey;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-12">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but somehow this doesnt seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/Insane415/pen/WMXdVy

Comment: By “only the padding” you mean, not the actual content area in between? No, that is not directly possible, and also not what `background-clip: padding-box` does. The easiest way to achieve this would probably be if you switched the padding out for a border - then you can control the color of that border separately from the rest.

Comment: @Insane, added answer ,think thats what you where looking for, i would say solution 1 is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `absolute` positioning `:after` also `background-clip & background-image`.

**Solution 1:** using `background-clip & background-image`

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 120px;
  background-clip:  content-box, padding-box;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, white 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, grey 0%, grey 100%); 
}



.content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-12">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**

Using : `positioning`

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 120px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.container-fluid:after{
    background-color: white;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 120px;
    right: 120px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}


.content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-12">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without positioning & background-clip in this situation this would work ..

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 120px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background: grey;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-12">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you are looking for something like this:

```
.content{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Please let me know if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: Maybe this answer does not deserve an upvote, but it doesn't deserve a downvote either. So I am going to upvote to balance that downvote which it got unjustly.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Taurus